# Prune / Vacuum Neo4j indexes(3.0.6 enterprise)

Tags: neo4j, database-indexes

We use Neo4J 3.0.6 Enterprise and experience that our queries become very slow.

What we found out hat index files have become very large and probably need to pruned/vacuumed (like postgresql does).
The data we use changes very quickly over time and the index files have a lot of stale or marked deleted data.

Is there a way to do clean index files and if yes, how?